# TYPO3: PHP warning with latest version of EXT:news

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

i am using TYPO3 8.7.22 with tx_news 7.0.8. When opening the detail view of any news i get the following error:

```
#1476107295: PHP Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /Volumes/web/src/typo3_src-8.7.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 1302 (More information)

TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception thrown in file
/Volumes/web/src/typo3_src-8.7.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php in line 107.

52 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\ErrorHandler::handleError(2, "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given", "/Volumes/web/src/typo3_src-8.7.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php", 1302, array)
51 explode(",", array)

/Volumes/web/src/typo3_src-8.7.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php:
01300:     public static function trimExplode($delim, $string, $removeEmptyValues = false, $limit = 0)
01301:     {
01302:         $result = explode($delim, $string);
01303:         if ($removeEmptyValues) {
01304:             $temp = [];

50 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::trimExplode(",", array, boolean)

/Volumes/web/sites/lkg-augsburg/web-8/typo3conf/ext/news/Classes/Utility/TypoScript.php:
00024:     public function override(array $base, array $overload)
00025:     {
00026:         $validFields = GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $overload['settings']['overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty'], true);
00027:         foreach ($validFields as $fieldName) {
00028:
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `settings.overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty` is not set in TypoScript. Did you include the default TypoScript for news? If not, do that or set `plugin.tx_news.settings.overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty =` in your TypoScript template so it's an empty string instead of `null`.

Comment: Sorry, no solution. I use news with standard templates and static typoscript. I also added this line, but it the error remains.

Comment: Found it - your hint did help me! There was this line in a typoscript template in the rootline: overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty.backPid = 99 ... of course this converted the string in an array. Damn ... :-) Thanks!!